# Как работает данная строка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Объясните пожалуйста как работают эти 2 строки:

```
query = form.cleaned_data['query']
results = Post.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('title', 'body')).filter(search=query)
```

## views.py

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    query = None
    results = []
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['query']
            results = Post.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('title', 'body')).filter(search=query)
    return render(request,'blog/post/search.html',{'form': form,
                                                    'query': query,
                                                    'results': results})
```

## forms.py

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query = form.cleaned_data['query']`

Очень просто, получаем строку поиска. Например, пришел запрос следующего вида:
uri?tab=1&key=value&query=то%20что%20ввели%20в%20строку%20поиска

после валидации формы, то есть после вызова `form.is_valid()` form.cleaned_data будет содержать словарь: `{'query': 'то что ввели в строку поиска'}`
подробнее [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data).

annotate указывает как нужно составить SQL  запрос. SearchVector указывает по каким полям нужно проводить полнотекстовый поиск. Через filter передаем "аргументы" для SQL запроса.

Подробнее [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) и [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/326278/).

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли :)